# How to detect child browser self-close event rather than all close action in Cordorva inAppBrowser

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

This my scenario: I am using inappbrowser plugin to open an authentication web, if pass authentication, it redirect to an url which returns:

```
<html><p>Auth success!</p><script>window.close();</script></html>
```

I know we can detect close event by:

```
 ref.addEventListener("exit", callback);
```

but what if I only want to detect that self-close event? Is there any method to pass msg and check whether auth succeed when exit events triggered?